# replacing an image in edit form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to replace the image in the edit form, below is the code that I'm using in the form to upload the image. It creates a path and URL which are then saved to a database.

```
   var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
   var filename = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
   var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/upload"),filename);
   image.Save(path);
   orgObj.AvatarUrl = Url.Content(Path.Combine("/Content/upload", filename));
```

What should be changed in this code so that it can replace the image in the edit form?

Comment: What does the html with the form that has the image to be replaced look like?

Comment: If you reload the form then it is the same as on first time.